# How to implement a Postgresql specific feature in java, which hibernate doesn't support (a VALUES expression)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

**Context**:
So i'm writing a RestAPI using Spring boot. I have a very bulky endpoint, which makes a decent amount of queries. The database itself is big, averaging 10 mil rows per table (some hold 1k, one holds 100 mil, most hold 5mil-30mil). First query returns list of string Id's. From that point on we do more operations using these ID's.

**General Problem**: 
In some cases the endpoint is asked for a lot of these entities (1000 or 2000). Once we get them, we don't want to do the following queries using an IN clause, since that would be slow for that many id's. Fortunately Postgresql provides the JOIN VALUES expression, which makes the queries extremely fast, but it's syntax (more like the parameter binding) is unfamiliar to hibernate.
Syntax: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-values.html

**Specific problem** : Passing in a List entityId's in hibernate, makes it do
`entityId, entityId, entityId ...`
For a values expression, we need it to do:
`(entityId), (entityId), (entityId) ...`

**Question**: What would be the best approach to do this? Add this custom binding for parameters? If that is the best approach, how would i go about doing that?

Thank you for any ideas/suggestions in advance!